# How to connect python and C# winform

Tags: c#, python, winforms, pandas, machine-learning

Good morning. !!!

We want to develop a platform for machine learning using data from sensors.

The language used in the project is C# winform.

I want to excuter python from c# winform.

With winforms as the UI
I want to run the analysis with python and see the results.

numpy, pandas, etc... 
Python code for running a machine.

I would like to advise you if you know someone who has been worried about me or how.

thanks!!

Comment: what is this...?

Comment: @rsm That's the real question of this "question".

Comment: Sorry for the lack of explanation. I solved it on the basis that you explained below. Now I want to import the dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

You can execute Python in a new application with Process.Start ( https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e8zac0ca(v=vs.110).aspx )

You might have to wait until the Process is finished with Process.WaitForExit, and return the results somehow, e.g. via a separate file or by starting it using a ProcessStartInfo with `RedirectStandardInput = true`, so that you can read the output written with the `print( )` statement in python.

Comment: Thank you!!. I solved it !!. Now I want to import the dataframe.

Comment: I'm really sorry.
Can I read the data frame of pandas with c # winform after reading and processing the data?